# She could well be crazy

Tags: wordplay

My gramma always use to say:

> If you replace our with if you'll end up one later

never quite understood it...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Well, I think your gramma was talking about

> F**our**th and f**if**th, where you replace 'our' with 'if' and end up one later in the count.

Comment: "You can accept an answer in 8 minutes"...

Comment: You can feel free to leave this unaccepted for awhile. I'm told that gets you more views. Either way, I liked the puzzle. :)

Comment: The puzzles genesis I copy and pasted something and had to change the lesser to the greater, I thought it was neat.

Comment: "Actually I was thinking of twentyfourth and twentyfifth"